# iPhone TableView in a TableView

Tags: iphone, uitableview

I have a UITableView which displays a list. If I touch an item, it should navigate to another UITableView. If again an item is selected, it should navigate to an another UITableView.

Simply to say, it should work like a folder. The UITableView may contain a folder in it. When the folder is selected, it should list the files in it by an another UITableView, and so and so.

Comment: Rather then ask give-me-a-code-(please) question, show what have you tried already and what you can't do specifically?

Comment: I have an mutableArray which displays a list of files(jpg, zip, mp3, and even some folders..) in a tableView. I have stored those files in a directory. In the second stage I am trying to have a detailView controller which displays the properties of the particular file when touched in the tableView. Everything works. But the in case, if folder is selected, it should list the folder contents in an another tableView. I am stuck here in doing so..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't add a tableView in another tableView! It's not very common and easy to use. You will have problem at scrolling too.

If the user clicks a folder, just push another ViewController to your NavigationViewController-Stack and show the content of the clicked folder.

If the user clicks a file, show what ever you want.. A UIActionSheet or what ever.

Comment: Ok. How to push a tableView to a tableView. I'd like to list the files of the selected folder in the form of tableView. Is this possible?

Comment: you got 2 ways to do that. First: If the User clicked a folder, change the dataSource of your tableView and reload it or push a new View with a new tableView to the navigationController. (http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UINavigationController_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

Comment: The Method for pushing a viewController is "pushViewController:animated:"

Comment: Thank you. Was looking for this only.

Answer (score 1):

You have tens, no hundreds, of example of code to do this. If it standard feature of table view.

Read the [Table View Programming Guide for iOS](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/TableView_iPhone/AboutTableViewsiPhone/AboutTableViewsiPhone.html)
and see the related sample codes.

Answer (score 1):

if you just want a folder like activity then it is not a good idea to use table view.You can navigate to different views on simple click action.If you are using the list to display and want to navigate on click of any of the element in list then you must use table view.

use the link below for better understanding with table view
http://adeem.me/blog/2009/05/19/iphone-programming-tutorial-part-1-uitableview-using-nsarray/